# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit in eclipse in Amazon Cloud

Tags: java, eclipse, amazon-web-services, java-8, heap-size

I want to do performance testing of large files using java in Amazon cloud.

Task is to transform one file format to another and write the output file

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit in eclipse
```

I Got above exception when i try to run Larger file like above 700 MB file using java in eclipse in Amazon instance which is having RAM size of 32 GB....

I got no exception till running 570 MB file,exception fired after running 600 MB File.

Some google searches told solution to Increase Heap size of VM,I tried that also,
My Heap size setting is

```
-Xms4G -Xmx12G -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit -XX:+UseG1GC
```

I set Max size upto 12 GB ..But I am still getting this exeception of

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit
```

Can anyone suggest better solution for resolving this issue?

Comment: How big are you trying to make this array?

Comment: Depends of what kind of data you have and what do you do with them.  Basically it means that you consume a lot of memory.

Comment: You haven't described the file contents, but in general don't read the whole file into memory and then convert the whole file.  Read small chunks of the file, perhaps one line at a time, and write to the other file.  Therefore, there is only ever a small amount of data in memory.

Comment: Am using EDI x12 data ....trying to transform x12 to flat file transformation ....

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it is not an issue with heap size but you simply try to allocate array with index larger than 2^31-1 (Integer.MAX_VALUE). Can you try to use other structure than array? Or maybe try to partition the file?

Another option is to use -XX:+UseCompressedOops if your heap size is less than 32 GB and you are using 64 bit jvm. It will reduce the size of pointers from 64 to 32 bit.

Comment: *simply*? Taking into consideration that there are two headers per each `Integer`, allocating that many objects is ridiculous  sizes to begin with... And `UseCompressedOops` is on by default anyways. It will reduce the size of *ordinary* object pointers only, the other one is still `64` bits.  Also `Integer.MAX_INT`?

Comment: You are correct with UseCompressedOops. It is on by default in jdk 8 for  heaps less than 32 GB. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Used -XX:+UseCompressedOops option also in Vm arguments,But still returns the same exception...Cant able to increase array size ...since all exception thrown in jars used for EDI transforms